# Python : Number of items in tuple

Tags: python-3.x, count, tuples

I've a tuple like this:

```
('path1', 'path2', ('orig1', 'patch1'), ('orig2', 'patch2'))
```

I want to count the number of items

So, when I run this:

```
for item in tpl:
    print(item)
    num = len(item)
    print(num)
```

I get :

```
path1
5
path2
5
('orig1', 'patch1')
2
('orig2', 'patch2')
2
```

My expectation is:

```
path1
1
path2
1
('orig1', 'patch1')
2
('orig2', 'patch2')
2
```

## Notes:

Very new Python, I may be taking a totally wrong approach to this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isinstance` to check what the object is. You are currently using `len()` on `string`

**Ex:**

```
tpl = ('path1', 'path2', ('orig1', 'patch1'), ('orig2', 'patch2'))

for item in tpl:
    print(item)
    if isinstance(item, tuple):
        num = len(item)
    else:
        num = 1
    print(num)
```

**Output:**

```
path1
1
path2
1
('orig1', 'patch1')
2
('orig2', 'patch2')
2
```

Comment: I've used another method too, using if clause for type... `for item in tpl: if (type(item) is tuple): perform action1; else: perform action2`